# getting the value in selection php

Tags: php, html

I have this selection box if I choose other textbox will show and the problem is the data I put in there only get the value "other" even I put text in the textbox the only value it gets is "other" so what do you suggest me to do this.
I'm using $_POST['talent'] to get the value.

```
Talent:
    <select name="talent" onchange="if( this.value=='other' )   { this.form['other'].style.visibility='visible' }else     { this.form['other'].style.visibility='hidden' };" required/>
    <option value="Dancing">Dancing</option>
    <option value="Singing">Singing</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
    <input type="text" name="other" style="visibility:hidden;" />
    </select>
```

Comment: `$_POST['talent']` will give you the value of the chosen select option, not the value of the text input.

Comment: Add jQuery and add a onChange listener, show the PHP where you post the data. if($_POST['talent']=='other'){ //then get value from $_POST['other'] }

Comment: that's what I'm after
I want to get the value entered in the textbox if I choose other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_POST['talent']` will only return the value of the select element. If that value is 'other', that means that the user has selected that option. In that case, you need `$_POST['other']` to get the value they typed into the box.

```
$talent = $_POST['talent'];
if ($talent === 'other')
  $talent = $_POST['other'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `$_POST['other']` to get the contents of the text box. Also, you need to put the text box after the `</select>`.